# How can I map list.__contains__?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm trying to map the `list.__contains__`, but am getting the following error

```
In [31]: map(list.__contains__(3), [[1,2],[1,3]])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-613ca9e4966b> in <module>()
----> 1 map(list.__contains__(3), [[1,2],[1,3]])

TypeError: descriptor '__contains__' requires a 'list' object but received a 'int'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flip the argument order, or just use a `lambda` which is easier.

```
map(lambda x: 3 in x, [[1,2],[1,3]])
```

Equivalent to a list comprehension, which is a bit shorter:

```
[3 in x for x in [[1,2],[1,3]]]
```

Comment: Got it in just before me. The map needs to know which list instance's `__contains__` method it is invoking.

Comment: thanks for this, great trick  to use the list comprehension to get rid of the lambda, v. pythonic